# Implement insert a file path in summernote

Tags: jquery, angularjs, laravel

I am using Lararvel 5 with angular-summernote. Additionally, I am having problem trying to implement a insert file path in summernote. What I am trying to accomplish is that when a user clicks on the insert file button, the user would be prompt with a modal box which has a dropdown list of all the documents that have uploaded using a feature I created within my web app. When they have selected a file from the dropdown, a anchor tag is inserted into summernote. Was wondering how could I accomplish all of this ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you post some of the your code?

Comment: Yes I have, I looked on the source code for the video plugin and tried use that has a guide. however, going on the documentation website for summernote does not really help.